# touchstart event not poping up the keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard, tablet, touchstart

I have a project where I want to automatically popup the keyboard on the focus of the element.

I have bind the touchstart event to the element.
The element is getting focussed but the keyboard is not popping up.

I event tried putting a delay. But still no luck.

This is the code which I tried.

```
$("#id").bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    $("#id").focus();
});

$('#id').trigger("touchstart");
```

Any help would be appreciated.